# Several GET requests works differently from time to time in Java

Tags: java, http, https, network-programming

I write a program for analysing devices of local network. One part of the task is to get VENDOR by MAC-address. I wrote a code that read all MAC-addresses, it works well. For getting Vendors by MAC addresses I decided to use [this API](https://macvendors.com/api). Next you will see the method, that takes MAC-address as a parameter and just send GET request:

```
public static String getVendor(String macAddress) {
        String dataUrl = "https://api.macvendors.com/" + macAddress;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(dataUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                return response.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return "VENDOR NOT FOUND";
    }
```

This code is called in a loop:

```
public static void scanIP(InetAddress ip, NetworkInterface ni) {
        ConcurrentSkipListSet networkIps = scan(ip.toString().substring(1), 254);
        System.out.println("Devices connected to the network:");
        networkIps.forEach(deviceIP -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(deviceIP);
                String MACaddress = getMacAddrHost(InetAddress.getByName((String)deviceIP));
                System.out.println(MACaddress);
                System.out.println(getVendor(MACaddress));
                System.out.println();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that this code works completely different from time to time, I mean that one time it can return Vendor correctly, another time it returns "NOT FOUND".

I tried to increase different timeouts, set various additional parameters (that are not necessary here), but it didn't help. I should notice that if I debug this code, it generates Vendors correctly every time.[First example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wr4i.png)
[Second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg15v.png)

Comment: It is a paid service. Free plan is limited to 1000 req / day and 1 req / sec. It can cause this behaviour. And it is just one thing.

Comment: @zforgo Well, I knew about 1000 req/day, but haven't read about 1 req/sec. I just made program sleep for a while before sending another request, and now it works fine. Thanks.